# Loop infinito no método on_message

Tags: python

Olá, pessoal. Estou com um loop infinito no meu bot do discord, mas não sei como resolver.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import strings_codes #minha classe de string e códigos
import auxiliary_functions #minha classe de funções auxiliares


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.send_message(client.get_channel(strings_codes.test_channel_id), strings_codes.welcome_message)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        lower_command = message.content.lower()

        if lower_command.startswith('!'):
            await client.send_message(message.channel, auxiliary_functions.switch_command(message))
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, strings_codes.invalid_commands['wrong_prefix'])

client.run(strings_codes.token)
```

O método `on_ready()` chama o método `send_message()` com a mensagem de saudação e dispara o método `on_message()`, que também possui o método `send_message()` em seu escopo, assim, fazendo com que o bot fique infinitamente capturando a sua própria mensagem. Eu vi o código de muitas pessoas e eles não precisaram colocar uma condição para disparar o evento que possui o método `on_message()`. Como que eu resolvo isso? Grato.

Comment: Existe uma forma de ver se o utilizador é um bot ou não. `message.author.bot`. Com isto poderá ser filtrado quem enviou a mensagem, e ignorar todas as mensagens que os bots mandam. Deverá parar o loop. Outra ideia, será melhor caso a mensagem não comece com o prefixo apenas ignorar e não responder. Poderá torna-se chato em todas as mensagens ter o bot a dizer que foi utilizado o prefixo errado.